# Windows Batch script save file as date/time

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im using this code on a windows batch script:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%dd%%mm%%yyyy%
echo New folder name %date%
```

but the folder name is just `07on`

i need to be able to save the file as `dd-mm-yy h:m:s`

Answer (score 6):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to look at something like this:

Running this today (from a command prompt)

```
C:\>date
The current date is: Thu 07/04/2013
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)    

C:\>SET Today=%Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%

C:\>ECHO %Today%
```

Produces

```
2013-07-04
```

It works like this:

```
SET Today=%Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%
                  ^ ^ ^       ^          ^
                  | | |       |          |
               Year | Dash  Month       Day
                    |
                Number of chars
```

You can get the time values the same way, replacing the `%Date%` with `%Time%` and adjusting the offsets the way you need to get the format you want to get.

You might also find [this similar answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17376562/62576) helpful if you want to separate the year, month, and day into separate values.

Comment: Extending onto this, here is the format for making `%time%` filesafe: 
`SET Time=%Time:~0,2%.%Time:~3,2%.%Time:~6,5%` produces `10.25.02.86`

Answer (score 2):

This is a robust method to get date and time rather than rely on the PC regional settings.  Requires XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. Just enter `echo %time%` or `echo %date%` and it will tell you. Hope it helps!

Comment: original poster is aware of `%date%` and `%time%`, but that was not the question. How do you get it into a variable in the desired format?